# UIlabel's text truncation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a `UITableView`. In that, each cell contains a `UILabel`. But, text in `UILabel` is not truncating if it exceeds `UIlabel`'s frames width.

I have tried following options, but nothing is working.

1> set the `LineBreakMode` as `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` and `setNumberOfLines:1`

2> set the `LineBreakMode` as `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `setNumberOfLines:1

In storyboard also, same settings are present.

Here is the code snippet:

```
NSString * fullName;
// FullName assignment code
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
NSLog(@"textlabel width: %f , text size : %d ", label.bounds.size.width,fullName.length);
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
label.text = fullName;
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[label setNumberOfLines:1];
[label sizeToFit];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Can you share the code ??

Comment: Are you sure your label's frame is indeed exceeded? Maybe your label is wider than you think.

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: yes. In UI it is visible.. Text is occupying is some other UI element's space.

Comment: Where have you set the frame for the label ??

Comment: Read more about what `[label sizeToFit];` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you do `sizeToFit` which adjusts the `UILabels`s width accordingly to its content.

And by the way: Do you have a reason for using tags and not IBOutlet? I think you've set up the `UILabel`in Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this,

```
[label setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
```

Comment: This is happening because of sizeToFit not because of auto layout

Comment: I just recommended the answer... doesn't mean that you should down vote... You can down vote if the answer is not related to the questions or completely wrong...

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong. Question was not at all related to autoresizing and also you don't need to set autoresizing to none, by default it will be none. Sorry for down vote but i'll be happy if you learn something from me or if I learn something from you. Don't ever worry about voting. Its one kind of way to give feedback, take it positively.